# Node js htmlparser2 stream complete event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pipe, html-parser

Hey I am using htmlparser2 to parse the xml. following is my code

```
var htmlparser = require('htmlparser2');
var fs = require('fs');
var sitemapUrls = [];
var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
    ontext: function(text){
        if(text.match(/foo/)){
            sitemapUrls.push(text);
        }
    }
 });
 fs.createReadStream('./sitemap-index.xml').pipe(parser).on('end',function(){
   console.log(sitemapUrls.length);
 });
```

I am not able find whether do we have any event for htmlparser2 which tells us the parsing is completed.

I want to print the length of sitemapUrls array .

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in handler I need to add event 'onend' which will be called once parsing completes

```
var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
    ontext: function(text){
        if(text.match(/myntra/)){
            sitemapUrls.push(text);
        }
    },
    onend: function(){
        console.log(sitemapUrls.length);
    }
});
```